# I made a List of Array, it's not working well

Tags: c#, list

```
        List<int[]> LST = new List<int[]>();        
        int[] ARY = new int[2];                     
        Random RND = new Random();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++ )
        {
            ARY[0] = RND.Next( 100, 999 );      
            ARY[1] = RND.Next( 100, 999 );      
            LST.Add( ARY );                         
            MessageBox.Show( 
            LST.Count.ToString() + "\n" + 
            LST[i][0].ToString() + ", " + 
            LST[i][1].ToString());
        }
        foreach ( var x in LST )
            MessageBox.Show( 
            x[0].ToString() + " ," + 
            x[1].ToString() );
```

Hi.. experts !!

I'd like to have;

```
 Foo, Boo
 Poo, Voo
```

But, I got ;

```
 Poo, Voo
 Poo, Voo
```

At the middle point check, both of them look good.
But, At the final stage, I got flattened List (the last one is repeated).
Any goood explanations ?
Regards
(Yeah, I found that If I moved the ARY declaration within a for loop, the result would be fine though. I'd like to have the reason WHY..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating the array once and then you are changing its contents and adding it to the list multiple times.

Please note that a `List` can have two items that point to the same object. And this is what happening in your case. The `LST` list has two items that are pointing to the same array.

You can fix this by moving this line inside the loop:

```
int[] ARY = new int[2];
```

At the middle point check, the message box will show you the current values of the array which is what you just set.

To see this clearly, check the value of `LST[0]` in the second iteration of the loop before calling `MessageBox.Show...`. It will show the new values, not the old ones.

Or even better, in the second iteration, check the value of `LST[0]` after executing `ARY[0] = RND.Next( 100, 999 );` but before executing `ARY[1] = RND.Next( 100, 999 );`.

Comment: Thanks reply. But, how about middle point check, it shows correct LST values (it diffrentiate both of them). Regards

Comment: Big thanks. I guess, I need some time to think it over again (actually, I've spent couple of hours already), Regards

Comment: So, this one is the famous "reference value" vs "value value" thing ? again ? I have thought, I knew that one, but, now, I got big confusion.

Comment: Think about it this way: 1 `new` will give you 1 object. And since you are using `new` once to create the array, then you have a single array. Moving the `new` inside the array means that you create a new array each time you go through the loop.

Comment: And yes, this is because an array is a reference type. If you have a struct  (a value type) instead of the array, then it would be different.

Comment: Even the array of value types (like `int[]`) is a reference type.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you never re-initialize the array and thus are overwriting the same two places in memory again and again. Trace the program and you should see this easily.

Comment: Thanks reply. But, how about middle point check, it shows correct process. Regards

Comment: Has `ARY` been filled in twice by then or just once? Remember the first time there isn't anything special being done while the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. would be where you'd be overwriting that you don't see somehow.

Comment: At the middle point check, the ARY (yes, I have the only one ARY though) has filled with a "different" value pair. So, the LST shows the correct "different" pairs. Now, suddenly, at the last stage, the LST has flattened. Regards